# A matrix $A$ is invertible iff $A^TA$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Is the assertion below true or false?

- "A matrix $A$ of type $n\times n$ is invertible iff $A^TA$ is invertible."

**I already know that this can be easily checked using determinants but I'm curious if something like below can work.**

Is the following resoning is correct:

If $A$ is invertible, then $A^T$ is also invertible. Multiplying the inverses from both sides yield:

\begin{array}{lcl}
A^{-1}(A^T)^{-1} & = & (A^TA)^{-1} \\
(A^{T})^{-1}A^{-1} &= & (AA^T)^{-1} \\
\end{array}

But since $A^TA \neq AA^T$, it's FALSE. However the answer is TRUE. Why doesn't the above method work?

Comment: $A^tA $ is invertible means $det(A^tA)\neq0$ and that means $det A$ and $det A^t$ are both different from zero and A is therefore invertible

Comment: Where's the contradiction? If $A$ is invertible, then also $A^T$ is, so both $A^TA$ and $AA^T$ are invertible; why should they be equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *not* refer to the inverse of $A^T A$ or $AA^T$ before you have show that these matrices have full rank. This is one reason why your method can not work.

However, we can show that the kernel of $A$ is identical to the kernel of $A^TA$. Indeed, if $Ax = 0$, then $A^TAx = A^T0 = 0$. Moreover, if $A^TAx = 0$, then $\|Ax\|_2^2 = x^T A^T Ax = x^T 0 = 0$, which implies $Ax = 0$. This shows that $Ax = 0$ if and only if $A^TAx = 0$.

It follows that $A$ is invertible if and only if $A^TA$ is invertible.

Comment: How can you show that ker$A=$ker$A^TA$?

Comment: @Parseval: This is exactly what my second paragraph shows.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B=A^{-1}$ and $C=(A^T)^{-1}$.

$$BC=D$$
$$CB=E$$

There is not reason why $BC$ has to be equal to $CB$. There is no contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Your method to disprove it doesn't work because $A^{-1}(A^T)^{-1} \ne (A^T)^{-1}A^{-1}$ in general. You can also think about the ranks of the matrices if you would like to see another way, or look at $A^T$ as the matrix representing the transformation from the dual space.